# Jquery, expanding search form on top of navigation

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, forms, search

I am developing a wordpress site and wanted to insert a search form inside the navigation menu so that when you however over the search button (fontawesome) the search box expands and once expanded it allows the suer to type input and hit search; but if the user takes their mouse off the search box it should disappear.

A good example of this can be seen in at http://www.woothemes.com.

So far I have an issue of getting the search box top appear onto of the navigation items instead of keeping a blank space where it was; then to stay open until user removes however (at which point the navigation re-appears.

here is how far i have gotten with my basic knowledge of jQuery:  https://jsfiddle.net/ru0f2vy2/

```js
$(function () {
    var mglass = $('.fa-input');
    var form = $('.search_box');
    mglass.mouseenter(function () {
        if (form.is(':hidden')) form.show()
        form.animate({
            'width': form.width() == 100 ? '0px' : '100px'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            if (form.width() == 0) form.hide()
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* Search Box text */
#header_search2 {
 overflow: hidden;
 float: right;
 width: 85px;
}

.searchform {
 
}


#container {
 width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;
}


.fa-input {
  font-family: FontAwesome, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.search_box {
 display: none;
}

.search_text {
 width: 74px;
 float: left;
}


/* The rest of the CSSS */

#header_home {
 height: 600px;
 padding-top: 35px;
 padding-bottom: 22px;
 z-index: 10;
}


#header_home h1{
 border: 0;
 font: 0/0 a;
 text-shadow: none;
 color: transparent;
 background: url(img/logo2.png);
 width: 281px;
 height: 124px;
 float: left;
}

#header_home li {
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}

#header_home ul {
 list-style: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;

}

#header_home ul li {
 text-align: left;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 15px;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#header_home ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #62666a;
}

#header_home ul li a:hover {
 color: #029fe0;
 text-decoration: underline;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#header_home ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


#header_home ul ul li {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 
}

#header_home ul ul li a {
 width: 45px;
}

#header_home li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">  <!----- CONTAINER START ---->
 
 <div id="header_home"> <!----- HEADER START ---->
 
  <a href="#" title="Return to the homepage"><h1>QEPrize</h1></a>
  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Nominate &#x25BE;</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Judges</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search-Group</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Criteria</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Winners &#x25BE;</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Trophy &#x25BE;</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Charity &#x25BE;</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Donors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trustees</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact &#x25BE;</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>  
     <div id="header_search2">
      <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://www.test.dev/">
       <div class="search_box"><input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="search_text"/></div><input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf002;">
     </form>
     </div>
    </li>
    
    
   </ul>

  </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without JS. I have created a quick [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ru0f2vy2/1/) here

```
<div class="search">
   search
   <input type="text" />
</div>
<ul>
   <li>news
   </li>
   <li>Nominate
   </li>
   <li>Trophy
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but would this be compatible with older browsers? What about the search button?

Comment: The transition effect would work on IE > 9. On older browsers the search field would appear/dissapear